# Which problem do we face after switching from PHP 4.0 into PHP 5.3.3?

Tags: php

As we all [know](http://www.php.net/archive/2010.php#id2010-07-22-2) yesterday PHP released new version of 5.3.3. My question is following:

What kind of possible problems could we have if we update PHP 4.0 into up to date 5.3.3.? I mean were their any functions  or operators on PHP 4.0 that don't work on PHP 5.3.3. and kind of such a problems?

That's it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the official [PHP migration doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.php)...

Comment: But it talks about migrating from PHP 4 to PHP 5.0.x.

Comment: Big difference is between the Zend1 engine (PHP4.x) and the Zend2 engine (PHP5.x), even if there are some big differences between 5.2 and 5.3. Start by reading this guide. It should cover 90% of the changes that may cause problems. If you encounter other problems, read the other migration guides, concerning the PHP 5 version.